# Lisp script to parse csv and generate HTML table?

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to write a little Emacs Lisp script that reads a csv file from standard input, turns all the rows into a table then prints it to standard out (Unix).  I wrote a basic version that takes a csv string and outputs the table to a buffer.  However, I would like to turn this into a Unix utility script.

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script

(defun gen-row (lst)
  (dolist (elm lst)
    (insert "<tr>")
    (insert (concat "<td>" elm "</td>"))
    (insert "</tr>")
    )
)
(defun parse-csv-line (txt)
  (setq lst (progn
          (insert "\n<table>\n")
          (setq str txt)
          (gen-row (split-string str ","))
          (insert "\n</table>\n")
          ))
  )

(parse-csv-line "this,is,a test")
```

The output to the current buffer when run from within Emacs:

```
<table>
<tr><td>this</td></tr><tr><td>is</td></tr><tr><td>a test</td></tr>
</table>
```

Usage of the script:

```
./csv2html < foo.csv > bar.html; # emacs --script instead of perl -ane '...'
```

Comment: you might want to use #!/usr/bin/env emacs
since it'll give you whichever emacs executable it finds in the PATHs. I noticed that you and the answer use emacs from two different locations :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd wrap your routines to get what you're after.

*Note:* I did change the routines to simply `princ` the strings as opposed to inserting them in a buffer.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/emacs --script

(require 'cl)
(defun gen-row (lst)
  (mapcar (lambda (elm)
            (princ (concat "<tr><td>" elm "</td></tr>")))
          lst))

(defun parse-csv-line (txt)
  (princ "\n<table>\n")
  (gen-row (split-string txt ","))
  (princ "\n</table>\n"))

; (parse-csv-line "this,is,a test")

(defun run-it (&optional argv)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (if argv
        (find-file (car argv))
      (condition-case nil
          (let ((line (read-from-minibuffer "")))
            (while line
              (insert line)
              (insert "\n")
              (setq line (read-from-minibuffer ""))))
        (error nil)))

    ;; the current buffer has the file contents (or stdin contents)
    ;; now process each line
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (< (point) (point-max))
      (parse-csv-line (buffer-substring (point) (progn (end-of-line) (point))))
      (forward-line 1)
      (beginning-of-line 1))))

(run-it argv)
```

If you're going to do more involved processing of the tables, it might be easier to manipulate the input as lists to get what you want and then use the [`xmlgen`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/XmlGen) package to generate all the HTML tags.

Comment: Never thought of looking on the wiki, the Emacs *info* page for --script is woefully lacking.  I've updated my script to handle this case.

Comment: Each row is wrapped in its own &lt;table> but it's good enough for me.  Thanks.